# How to make Text font change dynamically evenly

Tags: swiftui

I know you can change the font size dynamically with the `.minimumScaleFactor` view modifier however the issue is that I have 3 textfields in a `VStack` and I want them to all share the same dynamic font size.

If you run my example down below and just tap anywhere you will see that it either works as intended or sometimes 1 of them ends up smaller or larger than the other two. I can't tell if this is a bug or am I missing something here?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "Tap the screen!"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(text)
                Spacer(minLength: 20)
                Text(text)
                Spacer(minLength: 20)
                Text(text)
                Spacer(minLength: 20)
            }
            .lineLimit(7)
            .font(.system(size: 100))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
        .padding()
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .frame(width: 1600/2.5, height: 900/2.5)
        .onTapGesture {
            generateNewText()
        }
    }
    
    private func generateNewText() {
        var verse = ""
        for _ in 0..<Int.random(in: 20...50) {
            verse+="example "
        }
        text = verse
    }
}
```

I want the font size to be the same for all three regardless how many or few words each line has.
[image: Good]

But sometimes one of them is larger or smaller (larger in this case) than the other two and I need to prevent it.
[image: Bad]

Comment: Why the `.frame(width: 1600/2.5, height: 900/2.5)`? Try removing that.

Comment: You misunderstood `minimumScaleFactor`, it is not for dynamic size changing but to fit text in space by decreasing font size... so every text block can be decreased differently depending on the remaining size for each.

Comment: @aheze It's just so that the window stays the same size.

Comment: @Asperi Okay, so is there a right way to get all three texts adjust evenly depending on its length?